# Make CSS float columns align at top

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/y88mq/1/

I have a simple layout with three containers: one, two, three. I am trying to get three to align at the top with one. Right now one and two are floated left and three is floated right. I tried combinations of clearing but it didn't seem to work. I would like to get this to work with just CSS.

```
<div class="left">one</div>
<div class="left">two</div>
<div class="right">three</div>

.left {
    background: red;
    width: 66%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    background: green;
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
}
```

EDIT: I would like to keep the source order the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must keep the order of the HTML the same, then all i can think of is to use:

```
position: absolute;
```

I have made the changes to your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hRdEf/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of CSS and its evil floats, I suggest you rearrange the order of the boxes. This will work fine:

```
<div class="left">one</div>
<div class="right">three</div>
<div class="left">two</div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/y88mq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just place the "right div" at the top of the listed divs.

```
<div class="right">three</div>    
<div class="left">one</div>
<div class="left">two</div>

..//rest of code
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y88mq/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="left">one</div>
<div class="left">two</div>
<div class="right">three</div>

.left {
   background: red;
   width: 32%;
   height: 200px;
   margin-right:  20px;
   float: left;
}

.right {
   background: green;
   width: 33%;
   float: right;
   height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap columns one and two in a div, you effectively float the wrapper div and column three side by side and aligned at the top. The wrapper div will hold columns one and two stacked.

Extra advantage of this approach is that you can choose the align columns one and two on one line if there is more space available.

Semantically, your columns would still be in the same order.